# Open browser from a service

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to integrate a instagram login into my app. What I want to do is to open a browser (I was thinking using a `UIWebView`) where the user logs in and I should intercept the `UIWebView`s redirect to get my access_token and close the `UIWebView`. This is simple to do from a `UIViewController` by implementing the `UIWebViewDelegate` and overwriting the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method, but I implemented all of the instagram code in a service class (all of the class methods are static so there is no reason to make an instance of the class) and I want to be able to show and dismiss the browser from this service (without access to the viewController so unable to add the `UIWebView` as a subview). Is this possible and if so how? Any other subsections?

I'm trying to do this since the login might pop up in more than one controllers and I don't want to copy the same code in n-th places.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is a `UIWebViewDelegate` method. You can use it as an instance method of any class that implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol — it doesn't have to be a view controller!

I suggest you make your instagram class something that is actually initiated (and use instance methods rather than class methods). Then implement `UIWebViewDelegate` on that class. That'll handle intercepting the redirect.

As for getting the web view on the screen, maybe you should define a delegate protocol for your instagram class (called `MyInstagramControllerDelegate` or something). In this protocol, define a method like this:

```
- (UIViewController*)viewControllerToPresentWebView;
```

As well as this, make yourself a view controller for showing the web view, called something like `InstagramLoginWebViewController`.

Then, inside your instagram class, when you need to present a web view, you first call

```
UIViewController *presentingVC = [self.delegate viewControllerToPresentWebView]`
```

Second you create an `InstagramLoginWebViewController`. Third, you have presentingVC present the web view controller you just instantiated.

The final thing to tie all this together is to remember that whenever you create an instance of your instagram class, you need to set its delegate.